# Can I safely combine CL7 and CH9 RAM?

Tags: windows-7, memory, compatibility

I am looking to upgrade a Desktop currently with 2 sticks of 2GB RAM, by adding a couple of sticks of 1GB RAM. I am unsure what I need to look at to check their compatibility. Both sets of memory run on DDR3, the current 2GB sticks are CH9, while the two I want to add will be CL7.

Will these two different types be compatible?

Is there something else I should be looking at to see if the RAM is compatible? Would I be OK to just put both types in the PC and see if at accepts the new RAM or am at risk of damaging something?

- **Current setup**: 2x2GB running at 1600
- **Change to**: 2x2GB running at 1600 + 2x1GB running at 1066

Comment: As an aside, typically, the less RAM chips you have, the better access the CPU (motherboard) has access to. So, you'd be better off getting 1 x 4GB ram chip, middle choice would be 2 x 2GB RAM and least performance would be 4 x 1 GB RAM. Of course, it depends on the motherboard.

Comment: 2x2GB would actually be faster assuming dual channel is used.

Comment: I never heard of CH... CL is CAS Latency http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAS_latency and it's not the only property for a RAM that counts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SDRAM_latency#SDRAM_access & memory clock speed ... Anyway, I tell you one thing, you are light years faster with more RAM than with using the swap file on the disk. Don't worry about clock speeds. You're not running benchmarks on a computer all day.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please give exact model numbers.  You have to explain what CL and CH memory is only because your incorrect usage of terms.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you set the speeds to the slowest it should be fine (assuming it doesn't automatically!) The most important thing is that the voltage is the same.

Comment: So voltage is determined by DDR3, which is the same on both. I believe that CL7/CH9 is the speed, is this correct? How would I set the speed?

Comment: The speed is set in the BIOS and the speed and timings would be printed on a sticker the RAM itself. If you can find a model number for each type of RAM I can help that way.

Comment: I have added the speeds to the question. taking the advice of as few chips as possible; it appears to me that just keeping the faster bigger chips would be better than adding two extra slower chips. Does it look the same to you?

Comment: If you were to add the extra 2 sticks, you would have to have them all running at 1066. Some programs will run quicker with more RAM, and some will run quicker with faster RAM. I assume you're running a 64bit version of Windows 7?

Comment: Yes I will be on windows 7. Currently I use the 2*1GB sticks in XP and have some memory issues with large Excel workbooks. I am upgrading to a new system with the 2*2GB sticks on Win 7 and am wondering if it is worth migrating the old RAM across with me.

Comment: It's a job to say, it will vary from one program to another. Are you running a 64 bit version of Windows?

Comment: I will be running windows 7 64-bit

Comment: I would give it a try then and see how it works out. What motherboard do you have? They'll need to be in matched slots...

Comment: @Pezzzz   for the voltage bet thing is to check the specification of the RAM. There are a few possible voltages that DDR1,DDR2,DDR3 RAM might have.. I wouldn't assume it based on which specific DDRx RAM it is. IT may be that there's a general rule that DDR1 tends to be this voltage, DDR2 this, e.t.c. but worth checking the voltage 'cos maybe sometimes a particular e,g, DDR2 could be a common voltage or could be a more uncommon voltage.

Comment: @Pezzzz look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR_SDRAM     DDR1 could be either of "2.5/2.6"   DDR4 could be voltage of either of "1.05/1.2"    So don't just assume you know the voltage because of the DDR number. Check the voltage separately looking at the RAM specification.  And check what voltage the motherboard supports too . And perhaps some RAM could be non-standard too,for some reason. Also sometimes people overvolt or undervolt..